# No view found for id: Activity to Fragment inflated in a NavigationDrawer

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments

I know this question might have been asked so much but out of all those answers I've went through, non didn't work for me. I get this exception when I intent from an activity to a fragment inflated to a NavigationDrawer Activity:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0800c6 (xyz.ummo.user:id/frame) for fragment MyProfileFragment{16c76dd4 (91011ab5-3b76-4ccb-8573-f2b49ba96f08) id=0x7f0800c6 }
```

I've tried almost all approaches of switching screens from an activity to a fragment inflated into a NavigationDrawerActivity. Please go through the following java code and xml layout as sub-headed:

Method I used to intent from Activity to Fragment:

```
public void finishEditProfile(View view){


    MyProfileFragment fragment = MyProfileFragment.newInstance("param1", "param2");

    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.frame, fragment , "");
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

MyProfileFragment.java which is the Fragment class:

```
public class MyProfileFragment extends Fragment {
// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;

private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

TextView thisOneNayo;



public MyProfileFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

public static MyProfileFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {

    MyProfileFragment fragment = new MyProfileFragment();

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    final  View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_profile, container, false);

    return view;
}

// TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);

    if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
      mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } else {
      throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
            + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

/**
 * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
 * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
 * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
 * activity.
 * <p>
 * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
 * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
 * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
 */
public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}
```

}

MainScreen.java class which is the container class:

```
public class MainScreen extends AppCompatActivity
    implements MyProfileFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
    NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{

private Fragment fragment;

private DrawerLayout drawer;
private NavigationView navigationView;
private Toolbar toolbar;
private ImageView messageIconButton;
private ProgressBar circularProgreesBarButton;

// tags used to attach the fragments
private static final String TAG_HOME = "home";
private static final String TAG_PROFILE = "profile";
private static final String TAG_PAYMENTS = "paymentMethods";
private static final String TAG_SERVICE_HISTORY = "serviceHistory";
private static final String TAG_LEGAL_TERMS = "legalTerms";
public static String CURRENT_TAG = TAG_HOME;

private boolean anyServiceInProgress = false;
private int serviceProgress = 0;

// flag to load home fragment when user presses back key
private boolean shouldLoadHomeFragOnBackPress = true;
private Handler mHandler;

// index to identify current nav menu item
public static int navItemIndex = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_screen);

    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    setTitle("Ummo");

    //initialise  the toolbar icons message icon and circular progress bar icon
    messageIconButton = findViewById(R.id.message_icon_button);
    circularProgreesBarButton = findViewById(R.id.circular_progressbar_btn);

    circularProgreesBarButton.setProgress(serviceProgress);

    mHandler = new Handler();

    drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


    // initializing navigation menu
    setUpNavigationView();

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        navItemIndex = 0;

        CURRENT_TAG = TAG_HOME;
        loadHomeFragment();
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_home) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_profile) {



    } else if (id == R.id.nav_payment_methods) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_service_history) {

    }
    else if (id == R.id.nav_legal_terms) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri){
    //you can leave it empty
}

private void loadHomeFragment() {
    // if user select the current navigation menu again, don't do anything
    // just close the navigation drawer
    if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(CURRENT_TAG) != null) {
        drawer.closeDrawers();

        return;
    }
    Runnable mPendingRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // update the main content by replacing fragments
            Fragment fragment = getHomeFragment();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in,
                    android.R.anim.fade_out);
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, fragment, CURRENT_TAG);
            fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
        }
    };

    // If mPendingRunnable is not null, then add to the message queue
    if (mPendingRunnable != null) {
        mHandler.post(mPendingRunnable);
    }

    //Closing drawer on item click
    drawer.closeDrawers();

    // refresh toolbar menu
    invalidateOptionsMenu();
}

private Fragment getHomeFragment() {
    switch (navItemIndex) {
        case 0:
            // home
            setTitle("Ummo");
            messageIconButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            circularProgreesBarButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();

            return homeFragment;
        case 1:
            // My Profile
            MyProfileFragment myProfileFragment = new MyProfileFragment();

            messageIconButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            circularProgreesBarButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            setTitle("Profile");

            return myProfileFragment;

        case 2:
            // payment methods fragment
            PaymentMethodsFragment paymentMethodsFragment = new PaymentMethodsFragment();
            messageIconButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            circularProgreesBarButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            setTitle("Payment Method");

            return paymentMethodsFragment;

        case 3:
            // service history fragment
            ServiceHistoryFragment serviceHistoryFragment = new ServiceHistoryFragment();
            return serviceHistoryFragment;

        case 4:
            // legal terms fragment
            LegalTermsFragment legalTermsFragment= new LegalTermsFragment();
            return legalTermsFragment;

        default:
            return new HomeFragment();
    }
}

private void setUpNavigationView() {
    //Setting Navigation View Item Selected Listener to handle the item click of the navigation menu
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        // This method will trigger on item Click of navigation menu
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {

            //Check to see which item was being clicked and perform appropriate action
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                //Replacing the main content with ContentFragment Which is our Inbox View;
                case R.id.nav_home:
                    navItemIndex = 0;
                    CURRENT_TAG = TAG_HOME;
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_profile:
                    navItemIndex = 1;
                    CURRENT_TAG = TAG_PROFILE;
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_payment_methods:
                    navItemIndex = 2;
                    CURRENT_TAG = TAG_PAYMENTS;
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_service_history:
                    navItemIndex = 3;
                    CURRENT_TAG = TAG_SERVICE_HISTORY;
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_legal_terms:
                    navItemIndex = 4;
                    CURRENT_TAG = TAG_LEGAL_TERMS;
                    break;
                default:
                    navItemIndex = 0;
            }

            //Checking if the item is in checked state or not, if not make it in checked state
            if (menuItem.isChecked()) {
                menuItem.setChecked(false);
            } else {
                menuItem.setChecked(true);
            }
            menuItem.setChecked(true);

            loadHomeFragment();

            return true;
        }
    });


    ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.openDrawer, R.string.closeDrawer) {

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            // Code here will be triggered once the drawer closes as we dont want anything to happen so we leave this blank
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            // Code here will be triggered once the drawer open as we dont want anything to happen so we leave this blank
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
        }
    };

    //Setting the actionbarToggle to drawer layout
    drawer.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);

    //calling sync state is necessary or else your hamburger icon wont show up
    actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

public void setAnyServiceInProgress(boolean anyServiceInProgress) {
    this.anyServiceInProgress = anyServiceInProgress;
}

public void setServiceProgress(int serviceProgress) {
    this.serviceProgress = serviceProgress;
}

public void goToEditProfile(View view){

    TextView textViewToEdit;

    String textToEdit = " ", toolBarTitle = " ";

    switch(view.getId()){

        case R.id.full_name:
            textViewToEdit = view.findViewById(view.getId());
            textToEdit = textViewToEdit.getText().toString();
            toolBarTitle = "Enter your full name";

            break;

        case R.id.id_number:
            textViewToEdit = view.findViewById(view.getId());
            textToEdit = textViewToEdit.getText().toString();
            toolBarTitle = "Enter your ID Number";

            break;

        case R.id.contact:
            textViewToEdit = view.findViewById(view.getId());
            textToEdit = textViewToEdit.getText().toString();
            toolBarTitle = "Enter your phone number";

            break;

        case R.id.email:
            textViewToEdit = view.findViewById(view.getId());
            textToEdit = textViewToEdit.getText().toString();
            toolBarTitle = "Enter your email";

            break;
    }

    MyProfileFragment myProfileFragment  = new MyProfileFragment();
    Intent intent= new Intent(this, EditMyProfile.class);
    String tag = myProfileFragment.getTag();
    intent.putExtra(EditMyProfile.CONST_TAG, tag);
    intent.putExtra("name", textToEdit);
    intent.putExtra("toolBarTitle", toolBarTitle);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void finishEditrofile(View view){

    Fragment fragment = new MyProfileFragment();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.frame, fragment, "TAG_PROFILE");
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

}

activity_main_screen.xml which is the layout of the fragment i want  to move to:

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main_screen"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:theme="@style/NavigationDrawerStyle"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main_screen"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_screen_drawer" />
```

app_bar_main_screen.xml which is part of the activity_main_screen.xml and contains the container for the fragments:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/main"
tools:context=".MainScreen">

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:id="@+id/message_icon_button"
            android:src="@drawable/message_toolbar_icon"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            />

        <ProgressBar

            android:id="@+id/circular_progressbar_btn"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:indeterminate="false"
            android:max="100"
            android:progress="50"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circular_progress_bar"
            android:secondaryProgress="100"
            />
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: You are doing a wrong cast with : "id/frame" . Take a look at what layout it does belong and attach it to the Fragment or Activity you are using.

Comment: can you clearly explain your point @cod-e-rection